# Pass 'not' category.id to relatedTo in Craft

Tags: entries, categories, relatedto, filtering

I have a search page that filters with these params:

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
    section: 'properties',
    price: range,
    search: query.location,
    relatedTo: status,
    order: priceDesc
}) %}
```

The `status` variable needs to be set to a 'not' this category (or an array of all the other categories), but I can't seem to phrase my param correctly.

I've tried both the string and array method with category ID's, like this:

`relatedTo: ['not', category.id]`

And this:

`relatedTo: ['or', category1.id, category2.id, ...]`

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the ids in order to achieve your goal. So instead of `relatedTo not` you need a normal related to but the `not` statement in your id

I'm not on my computer currently so I'll edit the exact code in about 2h but it's the same like that one 
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/22532/5557

`id.('and, not ' ~ idsOfEntriesYouWantToExclude|join(', not ')`
Is the important part. In order to get them you just select all entries that are related to the thing you want to exclude

**Edit**
untested but this should do it

```
{% relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(status).ids() %}
{# just for debugging to test if the queryString is correct #}
{% set queryString = 'not ' ~ relatedEntries|join(', not ') %}
{% set results = craft.entries({
    id: 'and, ' ~ queryString,
    section: 'properties',
    price: range,
    search: query.location,
    order: priceDesc
}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin! I had not thought of that approach. FYI for future reference, I finally got `relatedTo: ['or', catId1, catId2, ...]` to work. It looks like that parameter accepts 'or' and 'and', but not 'not'. My category list has 4 items and I was trying to exclude one, so I set my category ids to `craft.categories.id('not' ~ omitCatId).ids()`, then merged `['or]' to it and passed the array to relatedTo.